# No metro project templates in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Desktop?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

Both of the download pages for [for Desktop](https://web.archive.org/web/20131112183242/http://www.microsoft.com:80/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-express-windows-desktop) and [for Windows 8](https://web.archive.org/web/20131112183242/http://www.microsoft.com:80/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-express-windows-8) provide the same web installer called: "Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop". I installed it and here is its "New Project" window:

[image: New Project Window]

In [this tutorial page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh986965(v=win.10)#step_1__create_a_new_project_in_visual_studio), it says I should have templates like this:

[image: Create a hello world app]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC621219.png))</sub>

How can I get these templates? I'm using Windows 8 x64 RTM.

Comment: maybe running `devenv.exe /setup` can solve the issue.

Comment: @Steve: There is no "devenv.exe" in the express version and "WDExpress.exe" doesn't recognize "/setup" command.

Comment: you **have** this executable. It's the VS entry point. Looks inside program files folder : `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe` for a X64 computer

Comment: @Steve: Found one in "Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0" but not in "Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0", trying it now...

Comment: @Steve: Nope, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE" has no "devenv.exe" in it.

Comment: the one in 10.0 is VS 2010. Maybe my path is not exact, do a file search on devenv.exe

Comment: @Steve: "devenv.exe" in 10.0 says: "Operation could not be completed."

Comment: @Steve: I searched, do you have the express edition, too?

Comment: I was able to download 2 seperate installers from the URL you provided, maybe you clicked the same link twice?

Comment: @JMK: Are you sure you tried the express editions? Because I'm very sure that they both have the same link, which is http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9816758

Comment: Aah I downloaded the ISO's and they were both different, my mistake!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have most likely downloaded wrong Visual Studio Express version, maybe there is broken link on that page.
If you want to develop Metro style apps for Windows 8, download the proper Visual Studio Express here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/hh852659

Comment: +1 There is a version of Express for Desktop, and a seperate version for `Windows 8` aka Metro, the Desktop version won't have Metro templates, and they are provided in two seperate installers from the Microsoft site

Comment: It's strange that the download link in [microsoft.com/visualstudio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-express-windows-8) makes me download the desktop version. I thought they merged the two at first. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @ŞafakGür, if you install [`Express 2012 for Windows 8 with Blend`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/hh852659) on Windows 7, it gives the error `This product can only be installed on a computer with Windows 8 or later`.. because metro-style-apps are only supported on Windows 8..